# Is it possible to get detailed web request timings in C#

Tags: c#

I didn't know what I was missing out on until I came across this article on [retrieving timing details using curl](https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/).

Curl pulls out additional details like:

```
   time_namelookup:  0.001
      time_connect:  0.037
   time_appconnect:  0.000
  time_pretransfer:  0.037
     time_redirect:  0.000
time_starttransfer:  0.092
                   ----------
        time_total:  0.164
```

I've had a look around in C# and I can't find any request types WebRequest, HttpClient etc. that can give this level of detail?

Is there some way I can tease this information out using C#?